# URLs in mod_python Not Working as Expected

Tags: python, apache, url, mod-python

I'm building a web server with apache and mod_python. I've created index.py as I've seen others do, but unlike others I can't access web pages without adding a `.py` to the url.

For example, `http://127.0.1.1/commentsubmit` produces a 404, but `http://127.0.1.1/commentsubmit.py` brings up the page as expected.

Everything is in my index.py, and `http://127.0.1.1/` comes up fine, but nothing else without the `.py`. My other methods look like this:

```
def commentsubmit(req):
    rest of method
```

I'm pretty sure the problem lies in mod_python, but I have no idea what. Is there some sort of configuration setting that might do this? Something other than `from mod_python import apache` I should be importing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your apache server would have been configured to pass requests to filenames that end in .py to mod_python (if the file exist in the dir.)

There are a number of different solutions to make request to /commentsubmit get passed to your commentsubmit.py handler. The easiest would probably be to to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Add this to you [.htaacess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
RewriteRule   ^commentsubmit$  commentsubmit.py
```

This is a dated way to do things. I recommenced that you look at [pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/) (or pylons, or django, or one of the million other wsgi frameworks.) You can then have much better control over how to map ulrs to code, using route based url dispatch, or transversal based url dispatch.